# How to Build a 2D Weights Matrix in Keras?

Tags: python, matrix, keras, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to solve the problem of:

```
X*transpose(X) == const matrix
```

Where I need to find X (which is an N by N matrix).

I cannot figure out a way to represent X as the weights in keras. The dense layer forces a 1D shape. If I use Lambda with Embedding it won't accept the Embedding layer.